# Neo4j server is getting failed to start with the java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, neo4j

Neo4j server is getting failed to start with the below exception,

```
Oct 3, 2013 12:05:10 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Starting neo server failed, see nested exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:70)
    at com.Neo4J.src.EmbeddedNeo4j.createDb(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:66)
    at com.Neo4J.src.EmbeddedNeo4j.main(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:38)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.createInterpolator(AbstractConfiguration.java:319)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getSubstitutor(AbstractConfiguration.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertyConverter.interpolate(PropertyConverter.java:684)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.interpolate(AbstractConfiguration.java:432)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.interpolate(AbstractConfiguration.java:419)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.AbstractConfiguration.getString(AbstractConfiguration.java:1101)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.getWebServerAddress(AbstractNeoServer.java:285)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.configureWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:183)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:101)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.interpol.ConstantLookup.<init>(ConstantLookup.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.interpol.ConfigurationInterpolator.<clinit>(ConfigurationInterpolator.java:330)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
    ... 19 more
Oct 3, 2013 12:05:10 PM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

Here i am trying to start the server through programme And the programme code is,

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(DB_PATH)
            .setConfig( config )
            .newGraphDatabase();
        Configurator configurator = new ServerConfigurator((GraphDatabaseAPI)graphDb);

        configurator.configuration().setProperty(Configurator.WEBSERVER_ADDRESS_PROPERTY_KEY, "172.25.218.96");
        configurator.configuration().setProperty(Configurator.WEBSERVER_PORT_PROPERTY_KEY, 7474);
        WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper bootstrapper = new WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper((GraphDatabaseAPI)graphDb, configurator);
        bootstrapper.start();
```

Can anybody help me with this.....

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same log library versions in your project as Neo4j Server. This seesm like a case where your current setup is pulling in some other versions of Apache Commons Logging.